# How to integrate AppHarbor with Slack?

Tags: continuous-integration, appharbor, slack-api

There does't seem to be an official integration a.t.m.
How can I do it manually?

What I'm looking to achieve is:

1. Every time the build goes from PASSED to FAILED, a (sad) message should be posted on Slack
2. Every time the build goes from FAILED to PASSED, a different (happy!) message should be posted.

Comment: What have you tried? https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks - *Incoming Webhooks are a simple way to post messages from external sources into Slack.*

Comment: I'm interested in this as well. Tried incomming webhooks but no luck...