# AppHarbor Slack Integration

Tags: continuous-integration, appharbor, slack-api

I've been trying to set up appharbor to work with slackbot on Slack or Incomming webhooks but tough luck.

[How to integrate AppHarbor with Slack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28087223/how-to-integrate-appharbor-with-slack)

https://support.appharbor.com/discussions/problems/77288-webhooks-for-posting-notifications?unresolve=true

This is what i've found so far on the subject and i've created a discussion on their support but still nothing...

Any assistance on the matter is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to get this to work using Zapier as an intermediary...

Add a Web Hook from the Zapier side to their built in Slack integration.

Then they will give you a webhook URL. Add this as a Service Hook in Appharbor. I needed to then push a build so that Zapier had a sample hook to work off of and then I did some simple filtering (only show fails for example) and configure the Slack channel and it was up and running in < 10 mins.